# Parsing aws-clite-gateway-api response issue

Tags: json, rest, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

Here is my JSON response. I want to parse the below JSON and get Site_id from header.location. I am able to get Status, Message values but not location value.

It is actually response header, I am trying to parse.

Please, anyone can help here?

```
    var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
let awsbody = JSON.parse(process.argv[2].split('\\').join('') || '{}');

    var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    invokeUrl: awsbody.endPoint, // REQUIRED
    accessKey: awsbody.awsAccessKey, // REQUIRED
    secretKey: awsbody.awsSecreteKey, // REQUIRED
    region: awsbody.awsRegion, // REQUIRED: The region where the AapiKeyloyed.
    retryCondition: (err) => { // OPTIONAL: Callback to further control if request should be retried.  Uses axon-

retry plugin.
        return err.response && err.response.status === 500;
    }
});

var pathParams = awsbody.awsPathParams;
// Template syntax follows url-template https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-template
var pathTemplate = awsbody.awsPathTemplate; // '/api/v1/sites'
var method = awsbody.method; // 'POST';
var additionalParams = awsbody.awsAdditionalParams; //queryParams & Headers if any
//var additionalParams = {headers: { "x-apigw-api-id": 'vs2i50xvo4'}};

var body = awsbody.requestBody;
var output = {};


apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
    .then(function(result) {
console.log(result)

    }).catch(function(result) {
             console.log(result)
    });
```

Here is output: But I just need Status, StatusText, location under headers and data (@ bottom) as output. I am tried to parse the output in above code no luck.
Can anyone help to parse response.

```
    { status: 202,
  statusText: 'Accepted',
  headers:
   { server: 'Server',
     date: 'Tue, 12 Mar 2019 20:34:36 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'content-length': '61',
     'x-amzn-requestid': '400377cd-4506-11e9-b941-3984677a719c',
     'x-amz-apigw-id': 'WciqVH8pPHcFgWg=',
     location:
      '/transit-connectivity/api/v1/jobs/8125d985-3d90-473d-b799-c9974
     'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-5c8817db-5522b10bf2068ac2509ae35b;Samp
     connection: 'close' },
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-apigw-api-id': 'vs2i50xvo4',
        'x-amz-date': '20190312T203427Z',
        Authorization:
         'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJ4Y5DGRDNBQ2HBYA/20190312/us
cept;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-apigw-api-id, Signature=801d0887fd
a249',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
        'Content-Length': 245 },
     method: 'post',
     data:
      '{"site_id":"TDCLOUDTSTTD03","account_id":"109443356002","change
ider":"aws","region":"us-west-2","network_id":"vpc-0ab26280d5060105c",
01.128/25"]}',
     url:
      'https://vpce-09d3e2325f36b5527-8xogk1r2.execute-api.us-west-2.v
ites' },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername:
         'vpce-09d3e2325f36b5527-8xogk1r2.execute-api.us-west-2.vpce.a
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host:
         'vpce-09d3e2325f36b5527-8xogk1r2.execute-api.us-west-2.vpce.a
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername:
         'vpce-09d3e2325f36b5527-8xogk1r2.execute-api.us-west-2.vpce.a
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host:
         'vpce-09d3e2325f36b5527-8xogk1r2.execute-api.us-west-2.vpce.a
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     _header:
      'POST /qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept:
\r\nx-apigw-api-id: vs2i50xvo4\r\nx-amz-date: 20190312T203427Z\r\nAuth
DNBQ2HBYA/20190312/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=a
 Signature=801d0887fd4a8b86a1af51a02cede529962fc5cae84f4a10f23983100e0
h: 245\r\nHost: vpce-09d3e2325f36b5527-8xogk1r2.execute-api.us-west-2.
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/qa/transit-connectivity/api/v1/sites',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [TLSSocket],
        connection: [TLSSocket],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 202,
        statusMessage: 'Accepted',
        client: [TLSSocket],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl:
         'https://vpce-09d3e2325f36b5527-8xogk1r2.execute-api.us-west-
1/sites',
        redirects: [] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 245,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl:
         'https://vpce-09d3e2325f36b5527-8xogk1r2.execute-api.us-west-
1/sites' },
     [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        accept: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        'x-apigw-api-id': [Array],
        'x-amz-date': [Array],
        authorization: [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        'content-length': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  data: { status: 'success', message: 'request has been accepted' } }
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what you have tried to get the value, and also how you got the values from the data object ?

Comment: As per javascript code your json is invalid as per syntax take a look over my answer for this post

Answer (score 1):

varible result is not in json format actually, take a look at my code which is in valid Json format.

You can get location as you need now.

```
let v = '{"data": {"status": "sucess","message": "request has been accepted"},"responsecode": 202,"responsetext": "Accepted","headers": {"server": "Server","date": "Tue, 12 Mar 2019 20:34:36 GMT","content-type": "application/json","content-length": "61","x-amzn-requestid": "400377cd-4506-11e9-b941-3984677a719c","x-amz-apigw-id": "WciqVH8pPHcFgWg=","location": "/transit-connectivity/api/v1/jobs/8125d985-3d90-473d-b799-c9974","x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5c8817db-5522b10bf2068ac2509ae35b;Sampled=0","connection": "close"}}';

let value = JSON.parse(v); 
console.log("location :"value.headers.location);
```

Console:

```
  location :  /transit-connectivity/api/v1/jobs/8125d985-3d90-473d-b799-c9974
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, let me rephrase the question. It might help to see he actual problem.